# Symbol 'redeclared (signed/unsigned,precision) conflicts with

Tags: c++

Hej guys,

Need some help with this lint warning:
Symbol 'isCapable(std::basic_string) const' redeclared (signed/unsigned,precision) conflicts with....

There are two files:
header and source file

in header i have next declaration(which is part of class):

```
bool isCapable(std::string Name) const;
```

in source file:

```
bool Factory::isCapable(std::string Name) const
{
   //some code
}
```

I tried to include string in source file too but no use. It still show this lint error.
Any ideas guys why is those lines are conflicted?

Comment: Please, post a small example reproducing your problem.

Comment: check that this function is not part of any existing header you are including in your code.

Comment: also post the complete lint warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for stupid question. Actually conflict was because header was C header(with .h) while source file was C++ file(.cc) For just C we had defined bool as int since C doesnt have bool type. And well C++ has bool type...